# c compound assignment increment only right bits

Tags: c, hex, mbed, compound-assignment

I am new to C and working with a serial device and I have this line:

```
short DA, DacData;    
DA=0xFFF;
DacData = ((channel&0x03)<<14)|((serialA&0x03)<<12)|(DA&0x6AA);
```

How do I increment only the last part of DacData (DA&0x6AA) in my loop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you care about the last part overflowing?

Comment: Not sure. Probably not!

Comment: Then it's a simple `++DacData`...

Comment: @StoryTeller Will that change the values of the ((channel&0x03)<<14)|((serialA&0x03)<<12) part?

Comment: Of course. That's one nature of overflow...

Comment: This question is rather weird! `DA&0x6AA` is equivalent to `DA&0b11010101010`, which is just masking out the zero bits.  Are you sure the result of incrementing is what you want? If you really just want to set the last bit, use `DA & 0x6AA | 0x1` so the next guy won't be scratching his head for 10 minutes.  Since you mask off the lsb each time, the increment can never carry out of the lsb.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for your response! basically, the 0x6AA part is for outputting a certain voltage from a DAC, and I want to keep increasing the voltage but I didn't really know how. would masking off the lsb the way you said accomplish this?

Comment: Take a value for the rightmost 11 bits, say 257 (`0x101`) and apply the mask `0x6aa`. The result is `0x000`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DacData = ((channel&0x03)<<14)|((serialA&0x03)<<12) | ( (DA&0x6AA) + 1 );
```

Take into account that there is wrap around...

Comment: Thank you! Was thinking the same, didnt know if it was the right wayI can check if this works when I get to my lab. Will accept it as an answer if it does! Thanks

Comment: @TakuzoKimura - That will affect the other "parts" in case of overflow as well

Comment: @Spider-main  Sorry for the noob question but what do you mean by wrap around?

Comment: @StoryTeller I only want to increment the rightmost 12 bits (they control voltage on my DAC), but it will increment from the right, correct? as long as I stop it at (DA&0xFFF) it should be ok?